# Editing properties files w/o losing formatting

Tags: java

I have a properties (Java world) file with comments and key=value. I simply want to take backup of the file and edit few key=value. I need to edit the key in loop as the number of keys are not fixed and also the key names differ partly which is not a problem, but i am struggling to know how to maintain the format of the file (comments, spaces)?

```
 # ABC System Admin Database
       abc_jdbc.password=5667P7JiL7k221j+DmnVQ==

 # XYZ System Admin Database
       xyz_jdbc.password=489slP7JiL7k221j+LmnVQ==
```

and so on......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties from JDK does not remember previous state. You can use some other library for it, for example [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Layout_Objects)

Comment: +1. I was writing an answer on how to implement your own parser for this, but obviously this is much easier.

Comment: I have never used it. But I think that it tries to analyze loaded file and uses it while storing. http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html

Comment: Thanks a ton MarrLiss    for(Iterator iterator = config.getKeys();
                 iterator.hasNext(); ){
                 key = iterator.next().toString();
                 if (key.contains(keyContains)){
                  newValue = getValueFromUser("Enter new password for key: "+ key + " :" );    System.out.println(" New password  -- " + newValue); config.setProperty(key, newValue);
}else{ config.setProperty(key,  config.getProperty(key))System.out.println(" key  -- " + config.getProperty(key));
               }
             }
             config.save();